# sending video by hand-made protocol

Tags: ios, video-streaming, video-capture, custom-protocol

I'm going to develop an application, whose main task would be send video frames captured from device camera to server. Server uses protocol over TCP. I heard that Apple restricts developers from using any video streaming protocols, except HTTP live streaming. Is this information correct? Will be there any problems while approving my app in appstore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging into the topic, found some info, [here is another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979842/video-encoding-libraries-for-ios). And for video broadcasting from device we cannot use HLS.