# Video encoding libraries for iOS

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-encoding

I really stucked with that problem, because I haven't seen enough information in the internet regarding video encoding in iOS, however we can observe plenty of apps that deal with the problem of video streaming successfully (skype, qik, justin.tv, etc.)
I'm going to develop an application, that should send video frames obtained from camera and encoded in h.263 (h.264 or MPEG-4 it is under decision) to a web-server. For this, I need some video encoding library. Obviously, ffmpeg can deal with that task, but it is under LGPL license, which could probably lead to some problems in submitting the app in the AppStore. On the other hand, there are some [applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679649/using-ffmpeg-library-with-iphone-sdk-for-video-encoding), which are seemed to use ffmpeg library, but only [Timelapser](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/timelapser/id334437863?mt=8) clearly states this fact in app description. Does this mean, that other apps are not using ffmpeg or just hiding this information?

Please, share your thoughts and experience in this topic. I'm open for dicsussion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After googling and making some research in this area, I found this one library http://www.foxitsolutions.com/iphone_h264_sdk.html. They really use hardware encoding. I've examined demo example with instruments, and they showed me that while encoding, ~12% cpu is used and syscall `read()` constantly called. From that I can conclude, that their library uses standard AVFoundation's `AVAssetWriter` to write into the temporary file, and (most probably) concurrent thread is used to read this temp file for retrieving encoded frames.

Also, take a look at http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html. It is under GPL, but still can be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Foxit Solutions. Unfortunately they don't have any demo now - only email for contact. Do you know any other libraries that might help? I need to wrap H264 raw data with a container (e.g. mp4 container).

Comment: @LukaszCzerwinski I wrote my own code to address this problem a while ago (in 2012 i think). This code still need to be properly debugged as the project was abandoned. DM me if you're interested, I should still have sources of that.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, that would be great. I'm happy to DM you, however, your profile says "Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.". Moreover there is no PM on SO, so there is no way to send you a DM :)

Comment: Feel free to shoot me a message at: <my last name>.<my first name>1@gmail.com

Comment: Could you please send your code to me? Thanks!
@peetonn

Comment: @peetonn the first link is broken.